# Logging to multiple syslog servers - log4j

Tags: log4j, syslog

Can I send logging information to multiple syslog servers?
Our IT department has 2 syslog servers (for redundancy) and wants the application to log to both of them.
Is adding 2 lines for syslog host going to work?

I guess creating 2 separate syslog appenders (SYSLOG1, SYSLOG2) will work, but wanted to explore this path first.

Answer (score 3):

No, because each SyslogAppender can only have one host, not multiple hosts. You'll need to create two appenders.